# How can I express the NOT in terms of AND, XOR, XNOR

Tags: logic

I need to figure out how to express the NOT operator in terms of the operators AND, XOR, XNOR.

I need to show that this set is functionally complete, which I'm trying to do by showing that I can represent NOT and OR, a known complete set. But I have no idea where to begin when it comes to representing a unary operator (NOT) using binary operators.

EDIT: I figured it out. NOT A=(A XNOR A) XOR A

Comment: Actually NOR alone is a known complete set ...

Comment: This was an error, I meant to say XOR

Comment: What the **** is the question? Do we have XNOR or NOR or what???

Comment: It was corrected in the post: we have XOR, AND, XNOR. My question has been answered though. Thanks!

Comment: Good for you. What is left for posterity is a mess, because the accepted answer doesn't answer the question. Posterity will have to read the comments and edits carefully to figure out what the answer actually is.

Comment: I am new here and didn't know what to do when after realizing I had made an error. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have figured out the $\sf NOT$: to emulate $\sf OR$, what about
$$
\textsf{XOR}(\textsf{XOR}(x,y),\textsf{AND}(x,y))
$$
?

Comment: This works great, thank you. I was trying to figure it out using my NOT construction but this is definitely more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x\ \textrm{OR}\ x = x$.

Hint 2: $x\ \textrm{NOR}\ y = \textrm{NOT}\left(x\ \textrm{OR}\ y\right)$.

Comment: Sorry I actually made a mistake typing out the question. I meant to say XOR instead of NOR. I have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: @zulfe Well, then the Hint is that $x\ \textrm{XNOR}\ x = 1$ and that  $x\ \textrm{XOR}\ 1 = \textrm{NOT}\ x$.